# structure of commutative algebraic groups

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-groups

I've read that there is a structure theorem for commutative algebraic groups over an algebraically closed field $K$ namely they are the direct product of a semisimple group and a unipotent group.

> 1. Is there an analog for $k$ a non-algebraically-closed field (say perfect)? I'm interested in both the cases for characteristic 0 and p.
> 2. Are there other structure theorems for commutative affine groups over $k$? (e.g involving semidirect products or just extensions)

Comment: The terminology is misleading, you mean "diagonalizable group" instead of "semisimple group" (semisimple does not mean made up of semisimple elements).